# how to map the hash values to display in perl cgi dropdown

Tags: perl, cgi

```
    % hash = {
       "key1" : {
          "value1" : [
          "tester1",
          "tester2"
          ],
       "key2" : [
         "value2",
         "tester2",
         "tester3"
         ]
        }
```

I already have a list of keys in the array will display in the dropdown,  if I select `key1` in the dropdown , I just want `key1` values

```
  print $q->popup_menu(-name=>'name',-values=>\@LISTOFKEYS);
```

Comment: FYI, as of CGI v4.04 (released September, 2014), the HTML generation functions are no longer being maintained and their use is [officially discouraged](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI#HTML-Generation-functions-should-no-longer-be-used).

Comment: `key1` points to a hash reference but `key2` points to an array reference. Is your hash really that inconsistent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this using just Perl and CGI. If you want to change the contents of a dropdown dynamically, then you are going to need to use Javascript too.

Given the relatively small number of options in your list, it's going to be easiest to copy your data structure into a Javascript object and use that to drive the contents of your drop-downs (in a more complex situation, you might use Ajax to get the new data each time the drop-down content changes).

Here's a simple HTML page that demonstrates how this works. Your problem now becomes generating something like this file in your CGI program.

```jquery
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
var orgs = {
  org1 : {
    "repo1" : [
      "testuser1",
      "testuser2"
    ],
    "repo2" : [
      "testuser1",
      "testuser2",
      "testuser3"
    ]
  }, 
  org2 : {
    "repo3" : [
      "testuser1",
      "testuser2"
    ],
    "repo4" : [
      "testuser1",
      "testuser2",
      "testuser3",
      "testuser3"
    ]
  }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#level1').find('option').remove();
  $.each( orgs, function( key, value ) {
    $('#level1').append('<option value="' + key + '">' + key + '</option>');
  });

  $('#level1').change(function() {
    var newOrg = $('#level1').val();
    $('#level2').find('option').remove();
    $.each(orgs[newOrg], function( key, value ) {
      $('#level2').append('<option value="' + key + '">' + key + '</option>');
    });
  });

  $('#level1').change();
});

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Drop-down Test</h1>
    <select id="level1"></select>
    <select id="level2"></select>
  </body>
</html>
```

(My jQuery knowledge is pretty rudimentary - there may well be ways to improve my code)

In a production system, you might well be able to move most of the Javascript into a separate (static) file, just leaving the large `orgs` object to be generated each time your program is run.

And I'll just reiterate that we've understood that CGI's HTML generation methods are a terrible idea for about fifteen years. Please use [an alternative approach](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Alternatives) instead.